# Sort text in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, sorting

I am trying to sort user input as they type in JTextArea. For instance when a user types in "Joe Frazier" I'll like to store just "Joe" in a String defined as firstname and "Frazier" in String defined lastname. Here in my code I tried the split method to separate the Strings after every space. assigning firstname to the first String before the space and lastname to the second String after the space. I'm getting thrown Exceptions. What's wrong with the logic of my code. I am not sure if I am being clear.

Here are the exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java_101.InfoAdd$StudentData.keyTyped(InfoAdd.java:52)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6490)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java_101.InfoAdd$StudentData.keyTyped(InfoAdd.java:52)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6490)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class InfoAdd {
        JFrame frame;
        JTextArea text;
        JTextArea texts;
        String te = "Pale";
        ArrayList<StudentData> array;
        int y; 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfoAdd game = new InfoAdd();
        game.go();
        }
        public void go(){
            frame = new JFrame("InfoAdd");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
            JButton button = new JButton("Click");
            text = new JTextArea(10,20);
            texts = new JTextArea(10,20);
            JScrollPane paneu = new JScrollPane(texts);
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
            text.addKeyListener(new StudentData());
            texts.setLineWrap(true);
            text.setLineWrap(true);
            texts.setText(te);

            paneu.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            paneu.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

            panel.add(pane);
            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(paneu);

            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true); 
        }
    public class StudentData implements KeyListener {

      private String firstname; 
      private String lastname; 
      private String clas;

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        String jext = text.getText();
        String [] split = jext.split("\\s+");
        firstname = split[0];
        lastname = split[1];

        texts.setText("FirstName: " + firstname + "\nLastName: " + jext);
      }

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent eu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does appear to be clear enough however it might help if you add the stack trace for the error you get. This will enable developers to see where the problem lies. Keep the questions coming bro

Comment: Thanks Ravi! I posted this now with the code

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener and listen for keyTyped events. What happens if the user deletes a character? Instead you should be using a `DocumentListner` which will generate and event when a character is added or removed.

Comment: In your code I see that you are trying to show 2 text area components. One for input and one for output. Please explain the expected behavior a bit more (may be with an example). I guess user is allowed to type in multiple names on multiple lines in the input text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in the `keyTyped` method, which is called every time the user types a character. This means that if the user is typing `Joe Frazier`, it will be called first with the text `J`. There is no white space in there so `split` will only contain a single string, `split[0]`. You then evaluate `split[1]`, which throws an error because it doesn’t exists.

You should check the length of the array like that:

```
String[] split = jext.split("\\s+");
if (split.length == 2) { // How you want it to work with 3 or more elements?
    firstname = split[0];
    lastname = split[1];

    texts.setText("FirstName: " + firstname + "\nLastName: " + jext);
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks! This makes sense